# balance 2 API endpoints proportionally with Azure FrontDoor

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door

I am trying to balance 2 API Endpoints, on the same API management, to achieve a canary release trought FrontDoor. The first endpoint (let's say [www.contoso.com/api1](http://www.contoso.com/api1)) stands for old application release and the second ([www.contoso.com/api2](http://www.contoso.com/api2)) for the new one. In that way, i am planing to create a backend pool in frontdoor to balance proportionally 90% of request to the first endpoint and 10% to the second one.

I know know that the best way to do this is with 2 API Management services (like balancing to servers with different deployments), but is it posible just with one?

Thaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combination of [choose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose) and [set-backend-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) policies:

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(new Random().Next(10) < 9)">
    <set-backend-service baseUrl="https://www.contoso.com/api1" />
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <set-backend-service baseUrl="https://www.contoso.com/api2" />
  </otherwise>
</choose>
```

Comment: Is this policy for "Application Gateway"?

Comment: For Azure API Management

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that FrontDoor only allows to configure Backend Pools of hosts whose names are FQDN. I also did tests with TrafficManager but I got almost the same result. Both feature traffic balance by weight.

The only way I found to balance traffic to URLs endpoints is through "Application Gateway" but without the balancing functionality.